# Duvidas com value dos selects

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz esse formulário com os `selects` fazendo pesquisa direto do banco de dados e também fazendo triagem dos dados, mas na hora de enviar o formulário respondido o `value` que vai no `<option>` não é o valor que desejo e sim outro valor, como mostra no primeiro campo do formulário que seria `"REGIONAL"`. O `value` que entra é o da variável `id_regional`, mas quero a da variável `regional`.

Obs: Pra ajuda a entender melhor o funcionamento dessa parte do código https://www.dropbox.com/s/v34dyd920djpop6/45.zip?dl=0..

```
<?php
     include '/conexion.php'; 


    $query = "SELECT id_regional, regional FROM t_regional ORDER BY regional";
    $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>ComboBox Ajax, PHP y MySQL</title>

          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cbx_regional").change(function () {

                    $('#cbx_tipoUnidade').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="whatever"></option>').val('whatever');

                    $("#cbx_regional option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_regional = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/getRPA.php", { id_regional: id_regional }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_rpa").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cbx_rpa").change(function () {
                    $("#cbx_rpa option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_rpa = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/getTipoUnidade.php", { id_rpa: id_rpa }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_tipoUnidade").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cbx_tipoUnidade").change(function () {
                    $("#cbx_tipoUnidade option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_tipoUnidade = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/getUnidade.php", { id_tipoUnidade: id_tipoUnidade }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_Unidade").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cbx_Unidade").change(function () {
                    $("#cbx_Unidade option:selected").each(function () {
                        id_unidade = $(this).val();
                        $.post("includes/getInep.php", { id_unidade: id_unidade }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_Inep").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });


            function populate4(verificamodalidade,resultado){
                  var verificamodalidade = document.getElementById(verificamodalidade);
                      var resultado = document.getElementById(resultado);

                        resultado.innerHTML = "";
                             if(verificamodalidade.value == "CORREÇÃO DE FLUXO"){ //verificar se o valor da modalidade de ensino
                                var optionArray = ["|","SE LIGA|SE LIGA","ACELERA|ACELERA","TRAVESSIA RECIFE|TRAVESSIA RECIFE"]; //retorna os anos de ensino
                                 } else if(verificamodalidade.value == "EDUCAÇÃO JOVENS E ADULTOS"){ //verificar se o valor da modalidade de ensino 
                                var optionArray = ["|","MÓDULO 1|MÓDULO 1","MÓDULO 2|MÓDULO 2","MÓDULO 3|MÓDULO 3","MODULADA|MODULADA"]; //retorna os anos de ensino
                                 } else if(verificamodalidade.value == "EDUCAÇÃO INFANTIL"){ //verificar se o valor da modalidade de ensino 
                                var optionArray = ["|","BERÇÁRIO|BERÇÁRIO","GRUPO I|GRUPO I","GRUPO II|GRUPO II","GRUPO III|GRUPO III","GRUPO IV|GRUPO IV","GRUPO V|GRUPO V"]; //retorna os anos de ensino
                                 } else if(verificamodalidade.value == "ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL"){ //verificar se o valor da modalidade de ensino 
                                var optionArray = ["|","1° ANO|1° ANO","2° ANO|2° ANO","3° ANO|3° ANO","4° ANO|4° ANO","5° ANO|5º ANO"]; //retorna os anos de ensino
                                 } else if(verificamodalidade.value == "ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL ESPECIAL"){ //verificar se o valor da modalidade de ensino 
                                var optionArray = ["|","1° ANO|1° ANO","2° ANO|2° ANO","3° ANO|3° ANO","4° ANO|4° ANO","5° ANO|5º ANO"]; //retorna os anos de ensino
                                 }
                                        for(var option in optionArray){
                                           var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
                                              var newOption = document.createElement("option");
                                               newOption.value = pair[0];
                                               newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
                                               resultado.options.add(newOption);
                                  }
                         }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <br/><br/>
<h3>Informe os dados da turma:</h3>
Os campos com <span style="color: red">*</span> são de preenchimento obrigatório!
<br/><br/><br/>
        <form id="combo" name="combo" action="guarda.php" method="POST">
            <div>Regional :<span style="color: red">*</span><br/> <select name="cbx_regional" id="cbx_regional" required >
            <option value="0"></option>
            <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id_regional']; ?>"><?php echo $row['regional']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select></div>
            <br/>
            <div>RPA :<span style="color: red">*</span><br/> <select name="cbx_rpa" id="cbx_rpa" required>
            </select></div>
            <br />
            <div>Tipo de Unidade :<span style="color: red">*</span><br/> 
            <select name="cbx_tipoUnidade" id="cbx_tipoUnidade" required></select></div>
            <br/>
            <div>Unidade de Ensino :<span style="color: red">*</span><br/> 
            <select name="cbx_Unidade" id="cbx_Unidade" required></select></div>
            <br/>
            <div>INEP :<span style="color: red">*</span><br/> <select name="cbx_Inep" id="cbx_Inep" required>
            </select></div>
            <br/>
            Modalidade de Ensino:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
            <select id="mod" name="mod" onchange="populate4(this.id,'ano')" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="CORREÇÃO DE FLUXO">CORREÇÃO DE FLUXO</option>
            <option value="EDUCAÇÃO INFANTIL">EDUCAÇÃO INFANTIL</option>
            <option value="EDUCAÇÃO JOVENS E ADULTOS">EDUCAÇÃO JOVENS E ADULTOS</option>
            <option value="ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL">ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL</option>
            <option value="ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL ESPECIAL">ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL ESPECIAL</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
            Ano de Ensino:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
            <select id="ano" name="ano" required></select>
            <br/><br/>
            Turma:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
            <select id="turma" name="turma" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="A">A</option>  
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
            <option value="E">E</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>
            <option value="G">G</option>
            <option value="H">H</option>
            <option value="I">I</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
            Turno:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
            <select id="turno" name="turno" required>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="MANHÃ">MANHÃ</option>
            <option value="TARDE">TARDE</option>
            <option value="NOITE">NOITE</option>
            <option value="INTEGRAL">INTEGRAL</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>
            Situação da Turma:<span style="color: red">*</span><br/>
            <select id="situacaoTurma" name="situacaoTurma" required>
            <option value=""></option>  
            <option value="CADEIRA VAGA / PROF. EFETIVO">CADEIRA VAGA / PROF. EFETIVO</option>
            <option value="CADEIRA VAGA / CTD">CADEIRA VAGA / CTD</option>
            <option value="CADEIRA VAGA / ACUMULAÇÃO">CADEIRA VAGA / ACUMULAÇÃO</option>
            <option value="CADEIRA VAGA / SEM PROFESSOR">CADEIRA VAGA / SEM PROFESSOR</option>
            </select>
            <br/><br/>          
            <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Finalizar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Primeiro tens que resolver a situação da pergunta que está um tanto confusa e mal formulada.

Comment: Dei uma editada na pergunta ver se agora da pra entender melhor a situação.

Comment: Se quer o valor de `regional`, por quê não muda de `id_regional` para `regional`?

Comment: Porque id_regional e  referencia de outra na tabela para fazer a triagem nos outros campos também esta assim sempre o id de outra tabela vem no campo para poder ir fazendo a triagem ate chega no ultimo campo que e a Unidade.

Comment: Tentei não funciona.

Comment: Sim, olha ta dificil vcs entenderem se quiser da uma olhada como funcioana https://www.dropbox.com/s/v34dyd920djpop6/45.zip?dl=0, ai vc vai ver como funciona na pratica o banco esta dentro da pasta .

Comment: Humrum, só não sei se fiz certo. kkkk

Comment: ok amigo flw...

Answer (score 0):

Você está definindo o valor de sua option com o id_regional e não com regional, como quer. Altere a linha de option para:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['regional']; ?>"><?php echo $row['regional']; ?></option>
```

**Edição:**

Já que precisa de ambas informações, você pode concatenar os valores no value do option e tratar isso depois no PHP.

**No option, faça:**

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['id_regional'] . "_" . $row['regional']; ?>"><?php echo $row['regional']; ?></option>
```

Daí no PHP você pode fazer um loop nos valores (ou outra forma como preferir) e pegar ambas informações.

Comment: Eu sei meu amigo, mas eu tenho q ter essa variável id_regional no campo porque sem ela eu não consigo fazer a triagem dos dados

Comment: Editei a resposta para uma possível solução. Você pode colocar as informações concatenadas no value e tratar isso no PHP quando for pegar os dados.

Comment: Da uma olhada pra vc ver como funcionar o código completo na pratica https://www.dropbox.com/s/v34dyd920djpop6/45.zip?dl=0

Comment: Desculpe, mas o que quer que eu veja? Seu código tá do mesmo jeito que colocou aqui. Se você precisa dos dois dados, ou concatena ou monta de outra forma, um array bidimensional, talvez.

Comment: Era só pra vc ter uma ideia de como funcionar com ele completo.. Não da pra concatena, mas flw ae pela ajuda amigo.. vo ver se consigo resolver essa bronca kkkk...

Comment: bem, se não pode concatenar, você pode criar um hidden com name **id_regional**, depois criar um método JS que será chamado no onchange do seu select e atribuir o valor **id_regional** ao hidden. Assim seu form terá todas as informações que precisa.

Answer (score 0):

No script original da pergunta já está bem perto de uma solução que vou sugerir. Pois o evento onchange já está registrado.

No momento que o usuário escolhe a opção, atribua o label da opção a um campo tipo hidden.

Exemplo, crie um campo oculto

```
<input type="hidden" name="regional" value="">
```

No trigger do evento já criado (on change), adicione apenas 2 linhas conforme o exemplo abaixo

```
$("#cbx_regional").change(function () {

    // isso aqui pega o valor que você quer.
    var str = $("#cbx_regional option:selected").text(); 

    // Atribui o valor ao campo oculto.
    $("input[name=regional]").val(str );

    // Abaixo segue o script original sem alterar nada.
```

A vantagem nisso é um código mais limpo e fácil de manter.

Conforme você mesmo citou nos comentários, a técnica que consiste em concatenar o nome com o id é válida mas dificulta outras funções.

O campo oculto pode estar em qualquer lugar pois o jquery o procurará pelo nome e pela tag. Potanto não se preocupe em colocá-lo dentro da tag `<form>`

Comment: Não funcionou amigo

Comment: não poste comentários vagos se quiser feedback